# Extracting comma separated ObjectIds from a mysql column and retrieving fields from relevant Mongodb documents

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mysql table where in a column(selected_issue) i have objectIds of selected issues. The details of these issues can be found in a `mongodb` collection(issuemeta) from which i need to extract a certain field. The problem is in the mysql **selected_issue** column, there are certain entries which have more than one objectId's as comma separated. When i am trying to fetch the related data from Mongo, it is taking all the comma seperated values as single object Id and hence failing. Below is the suite for the same. How do i handle such scenario so that the comma separated values are treated as multiple object Id's?

> > Note: *for the entries with multiple object Id's i would need the mongo data in a single row as comma separated.*

```
def returnGuideDetails():
    for details in returndetails:
        opents_id = details[3]
        issueleveldata = "select * from issue_levels_data where ts_id= '" + opents_id + "'"
        Issueleveldata = sqlDbObj.query(issueleveldata
        for issue in Issueleveldata:
            issuelevel = issue[6]
            selectedissue = issuemeta.find({"_id":ObjectId(issuelevel)})
            for selectedissuelevel in selectedissue:
                print selectedissuelevel
```

> > **Error:-** bson.errors.InvalidId: '5b51952d9b989aaf3db06914,5b51955f9b989aaf3db06915,5b51958a9b989aaf3db06916' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string

Comment: Might we suggest *not* storing comma-separated values?

Comment: @Strawberry i strongly agree with you. This is not par as normalisation rules, but this is how the table stores data and i don't have the authority to modify it hence have to deal with it.

Comment: See FIND_IN_SET()